# How to set an ImageVector from resource?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-resources

I'm trying to set an icon for bottom navigation like so:

```
sealed class Screen(val route: String, val label: String, val icon: ImageVector) {
    object Home : Screen("home", "Home",R.drawable.outline_home_black_24)
    object History : Screen("history", "History", R.drawable.outline_history_black_24)
}
```

But it says I need to switch the parameter to Int.
Help is appreciated, thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Refrences like `R.drawable.outline_home_black_24` is not the actual `ImageVector` but Int references to help get them in code. To get the actual image you should use something like `ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.***)` to get the actual `Drawable` file. This means that the correct usage should be

```
sealed class Screen(val route: String, val label: String, @DrawableRes val icon: Int)
```

The extra annotation throws a warning if a drawable resource which is something like `R.drawable.***` is not passed

Answer (score 9):

You should use ImageVector.vectorResource function like this:

```
import androidx.compose.ui.res.vectorResource


sealed class Screen(val route: String, val label: String, val icon: ImageVector) {
     object Home : Screen("home", "Home",ImageVector.vectorResource(R.drawable.outline_home_black_24))
     object History : Screen("history", "History", ImageVector.vectorResource(R.drawable.outline_history_black_24))
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Not quite the answer for the question in place, but, maybe can help someone in need...

If you are using Jetpack Compose and want flexibility between using `ImageVector`, as `Icons.Filled.Favorite` and using a drawable resource, you can achieve this by using a helper class, like the following:

```
class IconResource private constructor(
    @DrawableRes private val resID: Int?,
    private val imageVector: ImageVector?
) {

    @Composable
    fun asPainterResource(): Painter {
        resID?.let {
            return painterResource(id = resID)
        }
        return rememberVectorPainter(image = imageVector!!)
    }

    companion object {
        fun fromDrawableResource(@DrawableRes resID: Int): IconResource {
            return IconResource(resID, null)
        }

        fun fromImageVector(imageVector: ImageVector?): IconResource {
            return IconResource(null, imageVector)
        }
    }
}
```

With that class you can create your sealed class accordingly:

```
sealed class Screen(val route: String, @StringRes val resourceId: Int, icon: IconResource) {
    object Home : Screen(
        "home", R.string.something,
        IconResource.fromDrawableResource(R.drawable.outline_home_black_24)
    )

    object History : Screen(
        "history", R.string.something,
        IconResource.fromImageVector(Icons.Filled.Favorite)
    )
}
```

Then, just call in your composable:

```
navigationItems.forEach { screen ->
    BottomNavigationItem(icon = {
        Icon(
            screen.icon.asPainterResource(),
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }

    ...
}
```

### UPDATE

I've released a lib with that implementation, if you need it, can be found here: https://github.com/ygorluizfrazao/compose-resources

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
sealed class Screen(val route: String, val label: String, val icon: ImageVector) {
    object Home : Screen("home", "Home", painterResource(id = R.drawable.outline_home_black_24))
    object History : Screen("history", "History", painterResource(id = R.drawable.outline_history_black_24))
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciated, Decline.